# How to make a usb device load my function driver?

Tags: windows, usb, driver, wdm

I have written a usb function driver. if I want any usb device that plugged in my computer load this driver rather than its real driver, what should I do? I only know if I change vid/pid when bus driver create pdo, I can make it. But I don't know if there is a easy way to do it. How to change the bus's behaviour? Can a filter driver make it? The platform is Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to implement a [HID (Human Interface Device)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) driver.  By following the HID guidelines, most functionality you need is already supported, without having to write a custom device driver.

Here are some links to get you started:

**Using the HID class eases the job of writing USB device drivers** 
http://www.edn.com/design/communications-networking/4336292/Using-the-HID-class-eases-the-job-of-writing-USB-device-drivers

**Touch, Input, and HID: Architecture and Driver Support** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487435.aspx

For redirection over a network, have a look at the [FreeRDP project](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP).  It's open-source, under the [Apache license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html), so you can pretty much do whatever you want with the code.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what my program to do is redirect usb, that is, plugged in one computer and use in another computer.  I need a custom fuction driver to deal with the usb request from the remote pc.

Comment: If you're connecting a computer to another computer, you need [more than just a software driver.](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/342-connecting-two-computers-with-a-usb-cable)

Comment: I transmit urb request via internet; each computer has a driver.

Comment: I think you need to tell us a little bit more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: to write a program like this product. http://www.incentivespro.com/usb-redirector.html

Comment: Well, why don't you study [this code](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP)?  It's released under the Apache license, so if you like it, you can adapt it to your application.

Comment: how to transmit data is not a problem(via tcp or rdp is fine), the problem is how to deal with data from the remote pc. it needs a driver to sumbit request to the bus, and get response. my question is how to make the device load my custom driver automatic

Comment: A problem that I'm confident that the FreeRDP project will show you how to solve.